# Trying to use user input to save list as a file, but keep getting an extra line that says "none"

Tags: python-3.x

I created a function to write the list that is saved as a txt file. When I run the program, under the user input I get a line that says "none". I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

```
def list_1_file(list_1):
    outfile = open('shape_lists.txt','a')
    for v in list_1:
        outfile.writelines(str(v))
        outfile.writelines('\n')
    outfile.close()
    print('Your list has been saved as a file named shape_lists.txt')

file_2 = input(print('Would you like to save your shape information as a' 'file(y or n)? '))
if file_2 == 'y':
    file_utilities.list_2_file(list_2)
else: 
    print('Okay, I will not save this data as a file.')
```

I expected the line to to allow me answer after the actual question without the added "none"

**output**:

> Would you like to save your shape information as a file(y or n)? 
>   Noney ~~~~~that y is user input, but the "none" always populates. Your
>   list has been saved as a file named shape_lists.txt

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this:

```
input(print('Would you like to save your shape information as a' 'file(y or n)? '))
```

The `print` function will print-out "*Would you like...*" and then return `None`. That  `None` then gets passed to `input`, effectively creating `input(None)`, which prints-out "*None*".

Just pass the prompt directly to [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function, because "*If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.*":

```
input('Would you like to save your shape information as a' 'file(y or n)? ')
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes perfect since, and I completely overlooked it.

Comment: @svale2 If my answer helped you, feel free to [upvote or accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).